# Tensorflow: calculate gradient for tf.multiply

Tags: tensorflow

I'm building a neural network that has the following two layers

```
pseudo_inputs = tf.Variable(a_numpy_ndarray)
weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(...))
```

I then want to multiply them using `tf.multiply` (which, unlike `tf.matmul` multiplies corresponding indices, i.e. c_ij = a_ij * b_ij)

```
input = tf.multiply(pseudo_inputs, weights)
```

My goal is to learn `weights`. So I run

```
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learn_rate).minimize(loss, var_list=[weights])
```

But it doesn't work. The network doesn't change at all.

Looking at tensorboard, I could see that 'input' has no gradient, so I'm assuming that's the problem. Any ideas how to solve this?

From reading tensorflow docs it seems like I might have to write a gradient op for tf.multiply, but I find it hard to believe no one needed to do this before.

Comment: What is the expression of `loss` ?

Comment: It's calculated with `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`. But I don't think that's the problem - the network is able to train other variables just not the ones I need

Comment: FYI about  .minimize: "This method simply combines calls compute_gradients() and apply_gradients(). If you want to process the gradient before applying them call compute_gradients() and apply_gradients() explicitly instead of using this function." the pb isnt here

Comment: I would suggest to share more code. As for loss, we can think thats not the problem, but the fact is that there is a problem we dont think about :)

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @郭同jet sadly I don't remember what the problem was, but it wasn't the gradient and I didn't write a new op. It was probably something stupid

Answer (score 0):

I thought the `pseudo_inputs` should be set as Placeholders in the first line.

And in this line:

```
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learn_rate).minimize(loss, var_list=[weights])
```

Since weights are to be trained in the graph by minimizing loss then it should not passed as a parameter here.

```
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learn_rate).minimize(loss)
```

Then you should first run the train using the samples(**you don't have labels**) you have.

```
for x_train, y_train in samples:
    sess.run(train, {pseudo_inputs:x_train, y:y_train})
```

And after that you can get weights by:

```
W_c, loss_c  = sess.run([W, loss], {pseudo_inputs=x_train, y:y_train})
```